# Java - .txt file being overwritten or deleted

Tags: java, filereader, overwrite, filewriter

I have a program where the server gets the client's ip address and prints it to a .txt file if they do not login to the server correctly. then if the client comes back to try and log in again, the server should read the file and see if it matches the user's ip address. If it does, the server will ban the user by closing connection to the client.

The problem is that every time I restart the server code, the user's ip address on the txt file is deleted. This should not happen - the user's ip needs to be permanently saved on the txt file.

I was thinking it might have something to do with the placement of brackets, loops, or maybe the tries being reset to 0?

Any ideas how I can fix this?

I'll post what I think is the relevant code below:

```
    import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String welcome = "Welcome! The server is now connected.";
        String login = "Enter username and password: ";
        String message; 
        //PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("userIP.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("userIP.txt", true);


        try {
            //Detecting the localhost's ip address
            InetAddress localaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("SERVER\n");
            System.out.println ("Local hostnameIP: " + localaddr );

            // Creating a server socket for connection
            ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234);
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection on "+localaddr);
            // Accept incoming connection
            Socket skt = srvr.accept();
            System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");
            // get Input and Output streams
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.flush();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream())); 
            System.out.print("Sending string: '" + welcome + "'\n");
            out.println(welcome);
            //String ip = localaddr.getHostAddress();
            InetAddress clientInetAddress = skt.getInetAddress();
            String ip = clientInetAddress.getHostAddress();

            //read file


String checkIP = "userIP.txt";

        try {

                BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("userIP.txt"));
                String line;
                int numofline = 1;
                System.out.println("Beginning to read the file");
                line = infile.readLine();

                while (line!= null) {
                    System.out.println("*******Line " + numofline++ + "*******");
                    String data[] = line.split(",");

                    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Element #" + i + " "+data[i]);
                    }
                    line = infile.readLine(); //reading the next line

                        if (data.equals(ip)) {
                            System.out.println("IP MATCHES");

                            //closing server
                            out.println("You are banned. Server closing.");
                            out.close();
                            skt.close();
                            srvr.close();
                        }
                        infile.close();
                    }


                            }           catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + checkIP + "'");            }           catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error reading file '" + checkIP + "'");             }
                        //login attempts            int tries = 4;          while (tries>0) {
                out.println(login);

                //login
                String username = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client's username: " + username);

                String password = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client's password: " + password);

                if (username.equals("hello123") && password.equals("mypass")) {
                    out.println("Correct login!");
                    System.out.println ("Client's IP Address: " + ip);
                    tries=-1;
                }

                else  { //if wrong login - give 3 more tries

                    tries--;
                    System.out.println("Number of tries left: " + tries);
                    out.println("Try again. Login attempts left - " + tries);

                }           }


                if (tries<=0){
                out.println("Wrong login - server closing");
                out.close();
                skt.close();
                srvr.close();

                //ban ip address permanently 
                System.out.println("local: " + localaddr.getHostAddress()); 
                System.out.println("client: " + ip);

                //writer.println(localaddr.getHostAddress()); //write ip address to file
                writer.println(ip);
                writer.close();
                            }
do {

            message=in.readLine();
            System.out.println("client> "+message);
            if (message.equals("password")){
                out.println("Access Granted");
            }else if (message.equals("bye")){
                out.println("Server closing");
                System.out.println("server> Server closing");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
        out.close();
        skt.close();
        srvr.close();
    }catch(BindException e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("A server is already running on the same port.");        
    }catch(SocketException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("Client has disconnected rudely.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print(":( Whoops! It didn't work!\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `writer`?  A `FileWriter`?  Was it opened in append mode?

Comment: Can you show how you initialize writer?

Comment: Yes. I'll post the rest of the code

Comment: I also just changed writer.println(ip) to writer.write(ip) and the .txt file does not get deleted! But i'm having issues with it not comparing the user ip to the one in the txt file and banning them

Answer (score 0):

after `writer.close()` try this especially if you use Linux base server:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileToEdit);
fos.getFD().sync();
```

Specifically, you need to trigger a Linux system
call known as `fsync()`, which tells the filesystem to ensure all buffers are written to
disk.